# Lazy loading ngFor

Tags: angular, typescript, iframe, ngfor

I have a problem with the lazy loading and Angular4. I have a a ngFor like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let wid of widgets"></div>`
```

the wid is like:

```
<div>
 <iframe [src]="url"></iframe>
</div>
```

and I need the wid start to load the iframe only when visible on the screen. Does somebody knoow any trick or module for Angular2/4? Unfortunately I cannot use jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to accomplish this

1) put the component in a module that isn't the main module, and lazy load it following [this](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/modules/lazy-loading-module.html)

2) add an `*ngIf="ready"` statement to the div, and a variable `ready = false` in your ts file. using a lifcycle hook change ready to true.

```
ngAfterViewInit(){ ready = true; }
```

Comment: The second solution were works fine...I had just to add a simple timeout because I had an iframe error about the change early of the variable "ready". Thx a lot